# Delete/Hide "Cart" in Big Cartel Art Site

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, bigcartel

Can anyone help me to delete or hide the "Cart" tab in my Big Cartel art website? I want customers to contact me directly to purchase. Thanks so much!

I tried deleting all of the code, and asking customer service for help, but they said this is beyond their scope and recommended I check here for ideas. I'm somewhat comfortable editing code.